# How to get variables from MySQL Query (multiple level array)?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, variables

I have the following:

```
$sql = "SELECT c.category_name
         , c.category_name_url 
    FROM blog_categories AS c 
      JOIN blog_articles AS a
        ON a.category_name = c.category_name
    WHERE c.category_status = 'online'
    GROUP BY c.category_name
    ";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

$category_name = $row['c']['category_name'];
$category_name_url = $row['c']['category_name_url'];

}
```

But it's not working (generating blanks).  I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know what the formal terms of what I'm looking for is so Google is no help =/.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Comment: Why are you JOINing on blog_articles - it doesnt look like you are using it at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

code was not running because you dint supply a valid resource for the mysql_fetch_array.
also $row will be a single dimensional array.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT c.category_name
     , c.category_name_url 
FROM blog_categories AS c 
  JOIN blog_articles AS a
    ON a.category_name = c.category_name
WHERE c.category_status = 'online'
GROUP BY c.category_name
");

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {

 $category_name = $row['category_name'];
 $category_name_url = $row['category_name_url'];

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$category_name = $row['category_name'];
```

Well, I vote for PDO, but I am pretty sure you can skip the 'c', as $row will refer to the fieldname. The c is just evaluated by the DBMS to associate the field with the propper table.

Comment: Also by using `mysql_fetch_array()` you can use indices. Ex: `$row[0]` for category_name, `$row[1]` for category_name_url etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should call mysql_query on your $sql (the sql query), you then call mysql_fetch_array againts the result of the call. Anyway, you should almost always call mysql_error to check for errors.

Comment: Ah, actually I did do that (I just didn't add that line in there) - edited for clarification :)